# Is there any way to upload Dataframe from google colab to kaggle as Datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I already have some Dataframe on colab and I need any way that allow me to convert this Dataframe to CSV file (I know how to do this) and upload the CSV file directly to kaggle as Datasets.

Comment: so your question is actually how to upload csv to kaggle? via api? button press?

Comment: Yes, directly from colab